# How to patch a package-info.java file when using modules?

Tags: java, javac, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am able to patch system module files using these instructions.
https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start#xoverride

When trying the same command to patch a package-info.java, the package-info.class file is not generated if the patched version has the same contents as the version in the module. But this behavior does not apply to non-package-info java files.

javac --patch-module java.base=src -d mypatches/java.base \
        src/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-info.java

In my original question I mentioned the following error:

package-info.java:2: error: package exists in another module: java.base

I am still trying to create a toy example to reproduce this error. The main difference is that I am using a custom system module (--system) when I get this error.

Comment: Never heard of "patching" package-info files.

Comment: And why is it that you need to patch the `package-info.java`?

Answer (score 1):

[JEP 261](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261) introduces `--patch-module` as applying to class files, so it *could* apply to package-info.class, too. But then it continues

> The effect of each instance is to change how the module system searches for a type in the specified module.

Since package-info does not define a type, the above sentence implies that `--patch-module` has no effect on `package-info`.

Still, I believe the exact error message given is an accidental artifact of under specified behavior, as if `package-info.java` was compiled as being associated to the unnamed package despite being on the patch path.

Comment: It is possible to patch package-info.java files. I updated my question after experimenting a bit more. I'll update this question if I get any tips from  the openjdk compiler-dev mailing list.